# run 'make' in a folder, come out 'all rights reserved'

Tags: makefile, administration

Here is a simple question but I really wanna figure out.

When I tried to run '**make**' in a folder, it came out '**Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright ... all rights reserved**'. There were the only two sentences it came out.

May I ask is it just a simple administration-needed problem?? If it is, is there a way that I can solve this problem?

I checked the permissions of my folders, and they are all allowed to be full controlled.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All rights reserved" is a legal term relating to the copyright of Windows. It does not indicate anything technically wrong such as folder permissions.

Under normal circumstances, `make` does not do anything if all the targets are up to date.

Comment: oh,okay,thank you very much! May I ask why do we usually need to do 'make' after 'cmake ..' ? is it used to check the up-to-date situation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about `cmake`.

Comment: You should ask a separate question about cmake if you have it.  However, be aware that cmake is a "build profile generator".  That is, cmake does _not_ actually build your product.  Instead, it generates the control files that other tools use to build your product.  That other tool could be `make`, or it could be Microsoft Visual Studio, or it could be MacOSX Xcode, or Eclipse, etc.  Your invocation of cmake chooses what generator it uses.  After you run cmake to generate the control files, you have to run the tool itself (make, xcodebuild, devenv.exe, etc.) to do the build.